# How to hide select options that are present in another collection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have 2 lists on my page, a total list of all available options, and a selected options list.

When selecting a option from the all available options and adding it to my selected options list i want the option selected to be hidden in the select list for all available options, not removed but hidden.

Here is a link to some code i made that has the basics of the page but not the part about hiding, a java script or angular solution to this is much appreciated.

[Link to plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLcyk0QWpAZsMXpIWcky)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js" integrity="sha256-+f0njwC9E3IT9zDPry5DSIcGdSxQYezBaStQ4L0ZRfU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Page header</h1>
    <div class="list-group">
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-show="!selectedWords.length">
        <i>No selected words</i>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="word in selectedWords" class="list-group-item">{{word}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <select ng-model="selectedWord" class="form-control" required="required">
        <option ng-repeat="word in allWords" value="{{word}}">{{word}}</option>
      </select>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="addWord()">Add</button>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

JS file:
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.allWords = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  $scope.selectedWords = [];
  $scope.addWord = function() {
    $scope.selectedWords.push($scope.selectedWord);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your add is not working.

Comment: "not removed but hidden" - so dynamically apply the css style `visibility: hidden`? This will leave a "blank" option in the list.

Comment: updated the link to plunker.

@MatthewCawley, well to hide them with css is a possibility too, i was thinking maybe angular had a way of handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do it is with a custom filter like so:

Note that this solution does not ever modify the `allWords` array, it simply limits (on the view) which ones are visible based on the state of the `selectedWords` array, which makes adding the items back into the list as simple as removing the word from the `selectedWords` array.

**UPDATE -- Added removeWord() functionality (also included font awesome icon library for remove word icon)**

**UPDATE 2 -- loading selectedWords from json file on page load**

**[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZyA1XtRkKsuPLMULg70p?p=preview)**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter("unselectedWords", function() {
  return function(list, selectedWords) {
    var unselectedWords = list.slice().filter(function(elem) {
      return selectedWords.indexOf(elem) === -1;
    });
    return unselectedWords;
  };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.allWords = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  $scope.selectedWords = [];
  $scope.addWord = function(word) {
    if (word != undefined && word !== "" && $scope.selectedWords.indexOf(word) === -1) {
      $scope.selectedWords.push(word);
    }
  };
  $scope.removeWord = function (word) {
    $scope.selectedWords.splice($scope.selectedWords.indexOf(word), 1);
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Page header</h1>
    <div class="list-group">
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-show="!selectedWords.length">
        <i>No selected words</i>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="word in selectedWords" class="list-group-item">{{word}} 
         <span style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 12px; cursor: pointer;" 
            ng-click="removeWord(word)" title="Remove Word">
               <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="color: red"></i>
         </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <select ng-model="selectedWord" class="form-control" required="required">
        <option ng-repeat="word in allWords | unselectedWords:selectedWords" value="{{word}}">{{word}}</option>
      </select>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="addWord(selectedWord)">Add</button>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Really nice! Exactly what i was looking for, i'll look into implementing it in my real solution tomorrow as it is night here now. 

I'll come back tomorrow and set the answer if it works.
Thanks a bunch mhodges!

Comment: @MichaelA Great - glad I could help! Let me know if you have any questions when implementing tomorrow.

Comment: this worked exactly as i wanted it to :) thank you so much.

Comment: Oh no, i've run into trouble now. After getting this to work i notcied that when selectedWords is set to an array on load, this no longer works :o

Comment: @MichaelA Can you elaborate more on that? What do you mean on load? Like in a document ready function, or in an ajax call, or what?

Comment: @MichaelA See the plnkr demo link in my updated answer - is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way: http://plnkr.co/edit/uCrU28z7WzkopNlx2LlK?p=preview

Change your markup by setting the value of the select to the index instead of the value:

```
<option ng-repeat="word in allWords" value="{{$index}}">{{word}}</option>
```

That way when you want to remove the word from the list you don't have to go searching for it using string comparison:

```
  $scope.addWord = function() {
    $scope.selectedWords.push($scope.allWords[$scope.selectedWord]);
    removeWord($scope.selectedWord);
  };

  function removeWord(index) {
    $scope.allWords.splice(index,1);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Joel,
Thank you for the quick response.
I may have been unclear, but what i want to do is keep the element in both lists, but hidden from the select.